# Differences of Markov chain is Markov

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

In my studies of Markov chains, I was tackled with this tough problem:

> Let $ \{ X_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty} $ be a homogeneous Markov chain with transition probabilities satisfying $ | i-j | > 1 \to p_{ij}=0 $ and $ | i-j | \leq 1 \to p_{ij} > 0 $ and we are asked if $ Y_n = X_n - X_{n-1} $ is also a Markov chain

I know without the condition on the transition probabilities this is not necessarily true but given what we know is it Markovian? I cannot prove it nor can I figure out a counterexample. I certainly would appreciate all help.

Comment: You shouldn't expect the differences to be Markov without some kind of space homogeneity. Otherwise all you know upon conditioning is that your last step was (say) to the right, but you don't know where the destination was. And the distribution of the next difference will in general depend on where the destination was.

Comment: "I know without the condition on the transition probabilities this is not necessarily true" How do you know that? Does what you know apply to this restricted setting?

Answer (score 0):

The chain $ Y_n = X_n - X_{n-1} $ is a Markov chain when $ p_{ij} = \alpha ( j-i ) $ for some probability mass function on integers. Otherwise, there is no reason that it will be a Markov chain.

Before going into the calculations, quickly look at the intuitive reason. Clearly form the definition of transition probability, it is clear that we must have $ Y_n := X_n - X_{n-1} $ take values in the state space $ \{ -1, 0, 1 \} $. If $ Y_{n+1} = 1 $, this will imply that $ X_{n+1} = X_n + 1 $. Thus this probability will be weighted sum of $ p_{ i, i+1 } $ where weights will be the probability of $ X_n = i $. If $ p_{ i, i+1 } $  is independent of $ i $, i.e., $  p_{ i, i+1 } = p $, regardless of the probabilities of what $ X_n $'s value is, we must have that the conditional probability is $ p $ (as the weights will be summed to $1$). This argument should be applicable for all values that $ Y_{n+1} $ can take, i.e., we need to have $ p_{i, i-1} = q, p_{i,i} = r, p_{i,i+1} = p $ with $ p+r+q = 1 $. In fact little more thought will show that if the transition probabilities only depend on the increment, the same argument should hold. In such a case, the original Markov chain is a random walk (with steps in a general set) and hence the difference should give the step at time $n+1$. Therefore, it is the case that $ \{ Y_n : n \geq 1 \} $ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, hence of course a Markov chain.

On the other hand, if the transition probabilities does not only depend on the increment only, there is no reason to think that there is a magical way that the weighted sums would become same for any $n$. Some calculation of conditional probability will provide us an example.

Assuming $ p_{i,j} = \alpha (j-i) $ for $ i, j \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $ \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \dotsc, \epsilon_n \in \mathbb{Z} $, we have
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P} \bigl( Y_{n} =  \epsilon_{n} , Y_{n-1} = \epsilon_{n-1}, \dotsc, Y_2 = \epsilon_2, Y_1 = \epsilon_1   \bigr) \\
&  = \sum_{ x_0 \in \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_{n} =  \epsilon_{n} , Y_{n-1} = \epsilon_{n-1}, \dotsc, Y_2 = \epsilon_2, Y_1 = \epsilon_1   , X_{0} = x_0   \bigr) \\
&  = \sum_{ x_0 \in \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{P} \bigl(  X_{n} = X_{n-1}+ \epsilon_{n} , X_{n-1} = X_{n-2} + \epsilon_{n-1}, \dotsc, X_2 = X_1 +\epsilon_2, X_1 = X_0 + \epsilon_1   , X_{0} = x_0   \bigr) \\
& = \mathbb{P} \bigl(  X_{n} =  x_{n} , X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, \dotsc, X_2 = x_2, X_1 = x_1   , X_{0} = x_0   \bigr)
\end{align*}
where we have set $ x_k = x_{k-1} + \epsilon_k $ for $ k \geq 1 $. Now, we note that
\begin{align*} 
&  \mathbb{P} \bigl(  X_{n} =  x_{n} , X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, \dotsc, X_2 = x_2, X_1 = x_1   , X_{0} = x_0   \bigr) \\
& =  \mathbb{P} \bigl(  X_{0} = x_0   \bigr)  \mathbb{P} \bigl( X_1 = x_1  \mid X_{0} = x_0   \bigr)  \mathbb{P} \bigl( X_2 = x_2  \mid X_{1} = x_1   \bigr)   \dotsm \mathbb{P} \bigl( X_n = x_n  \mid X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}   \bigr) \\
& =  \mathbb{P} \bigl(  X_{0} = x_0   \bigr)  p_{x_0, x_1} p_{ x_1, x_2}  \dotsm p_{ x_{n-1},  x_n }   \\
& =  \mathbb{P} \bigl(  X_{0} = x_0   \bigr)  \alpha( x_1 - x_0) \alpha( x_2 - x_1)  \dotsm \alpha (   x_n - x_{n-1})   \\
& =  \mathbb{P} \bigl(  X_{0} = x_0   \bigr)  \alpha( \epsilon_1) \alpha( \epsilon_2)  \dotsm \alpha (   \epsilon_n) .
\end{align*}

Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb{P} \bigl( Y_{n} =  \epsilon_{n} , Y_{n-1} = \epsilon_{n-1}, \dotsc, Y_2 = \epsilon_2, Y_1 = \epsilon_1   \bigr) \\
&  = \sum_{ x_0 \in \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{P} \bigl(  X_{0} = x_0   \bigr)  \alpha( \epsilon_1) \alpha( \epsilon_2)  \dotsm \alpha (   \epsilon_n)  \\
& = \alpha( \epsilon_1) \alpha( \epsilon_2)  \dotsm \alpha (   \epsilon_n) \sum_{ x_0 \in \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{P} \bigl(  X_{0} = x_0   \bigr) \\
& = \alpha( \epsilon_1) \alpha( \epsilon_2)  \dotsm \alpha (   \epsilon_n) .
\end{align*}

This clearly shows that $ \{ Y_n : n \geq 1 \} $ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $  \mathbb{P} \bigl( Y_{n} =  i ) = \alpha (i) $ for $ i \in \mathbb{Z} $.

Now, to come up with a counter example for the other case, let us take the following transition matrix on the state space $ \{ 0, 1, 2, \dotsc, \} $
where
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots  
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
The transition probabilities $ p_{i,j} $ will not matter for $ i > 2 $. Suppose that $ X_0 = 0 $ w.p. $1$. By, choice of the transition matrix, we have $ Y_n \in \{ 0, 1 \} $.  Now, we can compute some elementary probabilities, (using $ X_0 = 0 $)
\begin{align*} 
\mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_2  = 1, Y_1 = 1  \bigr) & = \mathbb{P} \bigl(X_2  = 2, X_1 = 1, X_0 = 0  \bigr) \\
& = \mathbb{P} \bigl(X_0  = 0) p_{0,1} p_{1,2} \\
& =  (1/2) \times (1/2) = 1/4 \\
\mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_2  = 1, Y_1 = 0  \bigr) & = \mathbb{P} \bigl(X_2  = 1, X_1 = 0, X_0 = 0  \bigr) \\ 
& = \mathbb{P} \bigl(X_0  = 0) p_{0,0} p_{0,1} \\
& = (1/2) \times (1/2) = 1/4 \\
\mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_3 = 1, Y_2  = 1, Y_1 = 1  \bigr) & = \mathbb{P} \bigl(X_3 = 3, X_2  = 2, X_1 = 1, X_0 = 0  \bigr) \\
& =  \mathbb{P} \bigl(X_0  = 0) p_{0,1} p_{1,2} p_{2,3}  \\
& = (1/2) \times (1/2) \times (2/3) = 1/6  \\
\mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_3 = 1, Y_2  = 1, Y_1 = 0  \bigr) & = \mathbb{P} \bigl(X_3 = 2, X_2  = 1, X_1 = 0, X_0 = 0  \bigr) \\
& = \mathbb{P} \bigl(X_0  = 0) p_{0,0} p_{0,1} p_{1,2} \\
& = (1/2) \times (1/2) \times (1/2) = 1/8 .
\end{align*}

Hence, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_2  = 1 \bigr) & = \mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_2  = 1, Y_1 = 1  \bigr) \\ 
& \qquad + \mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_2  = 1, Y_1 = 0  \bigr)  \\
& = 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2 \\
\mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_3 = 1, Y_2  = 1 \bigr) & = \mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_3 = 1, Y_2  = 1, Y_1 = 1  \bigr) \\ 
& \qquad + \mathbb{P} \bigl( Y_3 = 1, Y_2  = 1, Y_1 = 0  \bigr)  \\
& = 1/6 + 1/8 = 7/24. 
\end{align*}
Therefore, we have
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_3 = 1 \mid Y_2  = 1 \bigr) = \frac{ \mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_3 = 1, Y_2  = 1 \bigr) }{ \mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_2  = 1 \bigr) } = 7/12 
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_3 = 1 \mid Y_2  = 1 , Y_1 = 1 \bigr) = \frac{ \mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_3 = 1, Y_2  = 1 , Y_1 = 1\bigr) }{ \mathbb{P} \bigl(  Y_2  = 1, Y_1 = 1 \bigr) } = 2/3. 
\end{equation*}
This shows that the Markov property is not achieved.